# communicate between two parallelly running Async Tasks

Tags: android-asynctask

I have two Aysnc tasks running parallally in my application from main thread: say A and B. I need to update / refresh the values in thread A when some values changes in thread B. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using Handlers :D